How to validate nested Spark DataFrame with Pandera?
Is there any possibility to validate nested Spark DataFrame with pandera.pyspark? This is an example with StructType, but similar could be with ArrayType.
from pandera.pyspark import DataFrameModel, Field
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, MapType

data8 = [
    (("Anna", "Rose", ""), "NY"),
    (("James", None, "Smith"), "OH"),
    (("Julia", "", "Williams"), "OH"),
    (("Maria", "Anne", "Jones"), "NY"),
    (("Jen", "Mary", "Brown"), "NY"),
    (("Mike", "Mary", "Williams"), "OH"),
    (("Carl", "Jon", "White"), "OH"),
]

schema8 = """
name struct<firstname string,
    middlename string,
    lastname string>,
state string
"""
df8 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data8, schema=schema8)
df8.printSchema()
df8.show(truncate=False)

returns simple example DF:
root
 |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)

+----------------------+-----+
|name                  |state|
+----------------------+-----+
|{Anna, Rose, }        |NY   |
|{James, null, Smith}  |OH   |
|{Julia, , Williams}   |OH   |
|{Maria, Anne, Jones}  |NY   |
|{Jen, Mary, Brown}    |NY   |
|{Mike, Mary, Williams}|OH   |
|{Carl, Jon, White}    |OH   |
+----------------------+-----+

Next I want to validate this DF with my Pandera model, but I don't know how to describe nested schema in Pandera.
They are not work:
# idea 1
class Person(DataFrameModel):
    name: StructType([StructField('firstname', StringType(), True), StructField('middlename', StringType(), True), StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)]) = Field()
    state: StringType() = Field()
# TypeError: Data type 'StructType([StructField('firstname', StringType(), True), StructField('middlename', StringType(), True), StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)])' not understood by Engine.

# idea 2
class PersonName(DataFrameModel):
    firstname: StringType() = Field()
    middlename: StringType() = Field()
    lastname: StringType() = Field()


class Person(DataFrameModel):
    name: PersonName
    state: StringType() = Field()
# TypeError: Data type 'PersonName' not understood by Engine.

# idea 3
schema = pa.DataFrameSchema(
    {
        "name": Column(
            StructType([
                StructField("firstname", StringType(), True),
                StructField("middlename", StringType(), True),
                StructField("lastname", StringType(), True)
            ])
        ),
        "state": Column(StringType(), nullable=False)
    }
)
# TypeError: Data type 'StructType([StructField('firstname', StringType(), True), StructField('middlename', StringType(), True), StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)])' not understood by Engine.

during validation Person.validate(df8)
